# Multiple sets of migration files in one project?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-3.1

I refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations?view=aspnetcore-3.1  regarding on how to deploy a database in production. It suggests renaming the database in the connection string so as to create another new initial migration.

How does the new migration file coexist with all the migration files that have been added during the course of the project development?

When I call `update-database`, how does it know which set of migration files to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF has a special `__EFMigrationsHistory` table that keeps track of which migrations have been applied to the database. View the data in that table and you'll see one row for each of your migration applied. If you have a new migration that doesn't have a row in this table that's how EF knows it hasn't applied that particular migration yet and when you `Update-Database` it'll apply it.